# Consumir una Web Service PHP desde Java Desktop

Tags: java, php, webservice, java-swing

Para conectarme a la WS me han pasado las credenciales y el método.
Anteriormente tuve el error del Estilo de la WS que era RPC, lo resolví agregando un plugin a Netbeans.

Ahora cuando pongo la URL de la WS, NetBeans se pone a cargar y muestra un error *WsCompile*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al darle en OK veo que en directorio de mi Proyecto no me ha creado ningun archivo, y en Web Service References aparece :"Parsing WSDL...".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado con algo de Axis2, pero no logro implementarlo a NetBeans, tampoco utilizarlo.

Para tratar de facilitarme el uso de la WS decidí tratar de recrear la WS, llegando a saber que la WS que trato de utilizar está hecho con la **librería Nusoap de PHP**, y veo imposible pasarle las credenciales sin el uso de ésta librería que solamente es para la Web. Ante esto pienso pedirle al desarrollador de la WS que pueda pasar las credenciales por medio de parámetros.

Ahora como ya he recreado la WS de forma local, he intentado hacer mis pruebas con NetBeans y muestra el error de que no se reconoce el tipo de Respuesta que en mi caso es un **Array**, y los archivos de respuesta están con la codificación **ISO-8859-1**.

Este es el XML:

```html
<definitions xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:wssalud"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="urn:wssalud">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:wssalud">
      <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="get_busafi_activoRequest">
    <part name="nroDoc" type="xsd:string" />
  </message>
  <message name="get_busafi_activoResponse">
    <part name="return" type="xsd:Array" />
  </message>
  <portType name="wssaludPortType">
    <operation name="get_busafi_activo">
      <documentation>Web Service Datos Afiliado</documentation>
      <input message="tns:get_busafi_activoRequest" />
      <output message="tns:get_busafi_activoResponse" />
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="wssaludBinding" type="tns:wssaludPortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="get_busafi_activo">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:wssalud#get_busafi_activo" style="rpc" />
      <input>
      <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:wssalud" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </input>
      <output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:wssalud" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="wssalud">
    <port name="wssaludPort" binding="tns:wssaludBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://sitioweb.com/ws/ws_AfiliadoSPHLNS.php" />
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

No sé si habrá alguien que haya tenido estos problemas con una Aplicacion Java Desktop.

Información adicional: Uso NetBeans 8.2

Answer (score 2):

No se usar netbeans bien, pero para hacer un WS cliente java solo necesitas estos pasos en eclipse:

1. cree un proyecto java normal y luego clic derecho->new Web Service client->
2. pegar la url o archivo wsdl y bajar la barra a Develop Client
3. Esto genera varios archivos. La clase que hay que instanciar para consumir el Web service soap siempre es la que termina proxy.

Ejemplo:

```
public class ClienteSoapJava {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws RemoteException{
        ConversionServiceProxy servicio=new ConversionServiceProxy();//Clase que se genero automaticamente al pegar la url del WSDL (el nombre puede cambiar pero termina en proxy)
        double conversion=servicio.conversionRate("USD", "MXN");//Metodo del WS que estoy invocando. (El nombre del metodo siempre es distinto)
        System.out.println(conversion);
    }
}
```

No importa si el WS esta echo en java, php, o c#, la forma de crear el cliente WS siempre será la misma.

Comment: Lo he intentado pero muestra el error con el Tipo de Respuesta de la WS: **La referencia de tipo Array no está definido**.